# Blender: No objects append with textures

Tags: blender

Running Blender 2.82 on Macbook Pro 2017.

Every time I append objects from .blend files, the objects appear magenta. This happens in all viewport shading modes, eevee and cycles. For example, I will try appending .blend scenes, objects, collections or materials, but even though the material is attached to the objects, and a little icon of the material appears, it does not seem to be opening the texture file. When I try to append textures from .blend files, I cannot find any in the Textures subfolder.

I also cannot see UV meshes on the UV editor, even after unwrapping, though that may be a separate issue.

The files are free .blend files from Turbosquid, if that's any relevance.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Blender 2.8 doesn't load materials properly from earlier versions, and so you have to rebuild the materials from scratch.